# File "python", line 33, in <module> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Select an option [1-2]:'

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

This is My script

```
name = input("Hello, to proceed please enter your name:")
print ("Hello captain %s, we have a new mission for you... its is very important. are you willing to take the risk to lead this mission?" % name)
print (50 * '-')
print ("Option 1) Yes")
print ("Option 2) No Way!")
print (50 * '-')
do_mission = input("Selct a option [1-2]:")
do_mission = int(do_mission)
if do_mission == 1:
    print ("We are glad you were willing to take the job!")
elif do_mission == 2:
    print ("We are sorry but we need you, if you do not accept we will have to kill you. Comprende?")
    print (50 * '-')
    print ("Option 1) I comprende.")
    print ("option 2) I do not comprende.")
    print (50 * '-')
comprende = input("Select an option [1-2]:")
comprende = int(comprende)
if comprende == 1:
  print ("Good! We are glad you understand! Now, here are your instructions")
elif comprende == 2:
  print ("We are sorry it had to be this way...")
  print (50 * '-')
  print ("GAME OVER")
  print (10000 * '-')
print ("You %s are going to be our strategic thinker in this battle. We need you to think of EVERYTHING that could happen. We are going to be your eyes and ears and you are going to be our brains. EVERY decission matters, so make sure to answer carefully or bad things could happen to you and us..." % name)
print ("My final question is, are you ready to go into battle?")
print (50 * '-')
print ("Option 1) Yes!")
print ("Option 2) No!")
print (50 * '-')
battle = ("Select an option [1-2]:")
battle = int(battle)
if battle == 1:
  print("You went to battle and died... Guess you should have just answered no and stayed back...")
  procede_to_pass = ("Press enter to continue")
elif battle == 2:
  print ("You are smart! You and your whole team lived because peace = lyfe! :D")
```

The error happens in line 33. I think its a syntax error. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and [mcve] to ask better received questions.

Answer (score 1):

You want to take keyboard input and its type is an integer. In python you can get integer input by the line given below and store it in battle variable.

Replace Line 32 and 33 with this

`battle = int(input("Select an option [1-2]:"))`